# boost::asio::udp async response is not entirely received

Tags: c++, udp, boost-asio, packet, datagram

## Explanation

My program sends an udp datagram to a server. Using wireshark I see the query and the response from the server (79 Bytes).

## Send function

```
void Query::start_send(const std::string data, const QueryType queryType) {
    boost::shared_ptr<std::string> message(new std::string(data));
    socket.async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(*message), endPoint,
        boost::bind(&Query::handler_send, this, message,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    this->queryType = queryType;
}
```

## Start receive function

```
void Query::start_receive() {
    socket.async_receive_from(
        boost::asio::buffer(receiveBuffer, receiveBuffer.max_size()), endPoint,
        boost::bind(&Query::handler_receive, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
```

## Receive handler

```
void Query::handler_receive(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    if (!error || error == boost::asio::error::message_size) {
        std::cout << "Bytes transferred " << bytes_transferred << std::endl << strlen((char*)this->receiveBuffer.data()) << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Receive failed" << std::endl << error.value() << std::endl << error.message() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

## Console output

```
Bytes transferred 79
11
```

The bytes_transferred value is correct but my response buffer (char vector) "receiveBuffer" contains only 11 Bytes instead of 79 Bytes.

## Wireshark

#### Sending

[image: Wireshark sending datagram]

#### Response

[image: Wireshark receiving datagram]

Comment: The data you send seems to contain arbitrary binary data, not a string. You seem to have forgotten that `char` strings in C++ are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. That *null-terminator* is a byte with value `0`. You should not use string functions with arbitrary binary data.

Comment: A byte is a byte is a byte... Just because some of the data are strings, or at least can be used as strings, doesn't mean *all* the data is a long string that can be printed or otherwise passed to string functions. You need to know the actual protocol and structure of the message you receive, otherwise it will not really be sensible.

Comment: Thanks I have modified my char vector by an unsigned char vector and it is works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is with `strlen((char*)this->receiveBuffer.data())`.

`strlen` accepts a nul-terminated C-string as input. So it stops counting when it encounters the byte `00`.

You seem to receive mixed binary/text data. You can't simply print it out as a string.